# unable to update entity

Tags: jpa, entity

this is the method

```
 public  String changePassword(int id){
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();                   
      try{
          utx.begin();
           Wuser wuser= em.find(Wuser.class, id);
           wuser.setPassword(passwordv);
           utx.commit();
        return "login";
   }catch (Exception e) {               
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                                        "Error changing password! ",
                                                        "Unexpected error when changing password for  your account.  Please contact the system Administrator");
                context.addMessage(null, message);
                Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE,
                                                "Unable to change password ",
                                                e);
                return null;
        }
   }
```

this is the `jsf` page

```
 <f:view>
        <h:form id="change">            
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" border="0">
                Username: <h:inputText id="username" 
                                       requiredMessage="*"
                                       value="#{usermanager.username}"
                                       required="true"/>
                          <h:message for="change:username" style="color: red"/>
               Old Password: <h:inputSecret id="password"    
                                         requiredMessage="*"
                                         value="#{usermanager.password}"
                                         required="true"/>
                          <h:message for="change:password" style="color: red"/>
               New Password (verify): <h:inputSecret id="passwordv"   
                                                  requiredMessage="*"
                                                  value="#{usermanager.passwordv}"
                                                  required="true"/>
                                   <h:message for="change:passwordv" style="color: red"/>
            Id:  <h:inputText id="id" 
                                       requiredMessage="*"
                                       value="#{usermanager.id}"
                                       required="true"/>
                          <h:message for="change:id" style="color: red"/> 
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton id="submit" 
                             value="Create"
                             action="#{usermanager.changePassword(id)}"/>


            <h:messages style="color: red" globalOnly="true"/>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Please add a description of the error you're getting and maybe a stacktrace if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Hej radoslaf,

change your h:commitButton Code to this:

```
<h:commandButton id="submit" 
                             value="Create"
                             action="#{usermanager.changePassword(usermanager.id)}"/>
```

The property "id" is only known in connection with the usermanager which, i think, provides the currentUser Object you want to edit.

Greets Patrick

Comment: my main problem is i'm not able to update the entity if i do **em.persist(wuser)**.i'm getting a duplicate record but if i do **em.merge(wuser)** entity is not getting updated

Comment: how do i update the entity **utx.begin(); Wuser wuser= em.find(Wuser.class, id); wuser.setPassword(passwordv); utx.commit();** is the above code right to update an entity

Answer (score 0):

there was no issue with the code. the issue was the database user did not have the update privilege.

i found the error when checking the server logs.

i have suitable modified the code to validate the user.thanks for all the help